# "No shipping information available" in shipping area at frontend magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento version 1.8.1.0 with onestepcheckout extension.

Sometime its give me "No shipping information available" at shipping section in frontend. and also user can place the order without selecting any shipping method. order info page in backend display also "No shipping information available".

Previously Anyone faced this issue. please guide me to solve it.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

First check that whether order is working with normal checkout process (I mean magento default checkout for frontend.).

Please check whether shipping method is enabled for the location for which you want to place order.

Some shipping methods have option to select specific country in System Configuration.